# What is the best way in which ionic application code can be split?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, gulp

I am building an ionic app and as the application is going large, the code is also going messy. Right now the structure is like this :

[image]

How can i make my code modularized ? something like this :

```
js/
  `-controllers/
     `- controller_A.js
  `-services/
     `- service_A.js
  app.js
```

I also used `requireJS` but i didn't understand the concept. Right now i am using gulp to concatinate all the files under `js/` directory and bundle it into `bundle.js`.

Please tell me how to make a best structure on which i can build application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly encourage you to group your files (html / js) by feature rather than file type. This approach will significantly ease development for you.

So your directory should look like this:

```
app/
 login/
   login.controller.js
   login.template.html
   login.scss
```

You may use a task runner (Gulp / Grunt) to compile and copy the files into dest (www) directory.

Check out [angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) by John Papa. A great resource for angular's best coding practices.

Comment: Yeah it is but i have to include each js file in html also. Is there any way like i can make each controller and services in different files and then require that file into `app.js` and the by using browserify i can make a `bundle.js` which i can then link in my `index.html`. Thankyou very much for your reply @hamza-isaac

Comment: Yep. Actually with gulp you can compile all js files into one file (e.g. app.js) using gulp-concat plugin. Then you just need to include this app.js in index.html.